# Can I use Bad Toys on other people's babies?

Tags: evil-baby-orphanage

In the rules for *Evil Baby Orphanage*, it says for Bad Toys that "you may discard the toy from your Orphanage to cause any Evil Baby to take it's Unsupervised Actions during your Activity Step." Does this mean that I can discard a Bad Toy to make another Time-Nanny's Evil Baby do their Unsupervised Action during **my** Activity Step? The people I play with have assumed up until this point that you could only do this to your own Evil Babies, but in rereading the rules, this isn't actually clear. In fact, the word "any" seems to indicate that this can be done to other Evil Babies. The ability to cause other Evil Babies to do their Unsupervised Actions seems like a very powerful ability and would drastically change the flow of a game.

**Edit:**

We discovered that we initially thought it only applied to your own baby because the player cards are worded differently than the instructions. They read: "you may discard the toy from your Orphanage to cause ***an*** Evil Baby to take it's Unsupervised Actions during your Activity Step." This was the original cause of our assumption; this doesn't seem to indicate that you could target other Time-Nanny's Evil Babies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally took the time to ask directly on the [Wyrd Games forums](http://www.wyrd-games.net/showthread.php?33899-Evil-Baby-Orphanage-Rules&p=513779#post513779) and someone from Wyrd responded:

> Yes, you may discard a bad toy to make any baby in play (including your opponent's babies) take unsupervised actions.

So the answer is **yes, bad toys can be used to activate an opponent's Evil Baby's Unsupervised Action on your own Activity Step.**

Answer (score 1):

Everyone I have played with has interpreted 'any' as being any baby in play.  Does beget a bit of a question regarding babies in the time stream, but I have experienced consensus on other people's babies.

Comment: Indeed, you're now making me second guess if *we've* been playing it right.  Gonna go check if wyrd has set up a forum yet.